# React empty string appears as white space

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
export const formatAddress = address => {
  const {
    flatName,
    buildingName,
    houseNumber,
    streetName,
    city,
    postCode
  } = address;
  return [
    flatName || '',
    buildingName || '',
    `${houseNumber || ''} ${streetName || ''}`,
    city,
    postCode
  ]
    .filter(val => val)
    .join('\n');
};
```

My problem is that when houseNumber is received undefined, the empty string it appears as a white space on my app. How can I resolve this issue? I've tried using .trim() but did not work and my app crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: *"the empty string it appears as a white space on my app."* The white space you are seeing is probably the space between `${houseNumber || ''}` and `${streetName || ''}`. If you only want to add a space if `houseNumber` is set then you have to implement it as such.

Comment: You're right! I didn't realised that space. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling any ideas on how can I implement a white space when houseNumber is not undefined? I tried ```${(houseNumber && ' ') || ''}``` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can do `${houseNumber ? houseNumber + ' ' : ''}${streetName || ''}`. `houseNumber && ' '` will just evaluate to `' '` if `houseNumber` is truthy.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you. Works as expected. Really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about conditionally adding the space instead.

`${houseNumber ? houseNumber + ' ' : ''}${streetName || ''}`,

Answer (score 0):

instead of filter you can use map method :

```
 .map(val => val.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,''))
```